# Is there a way to display just one cell of an Excel spreadsheet on screen at a time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, xlsx

I have to review the quality of all the entries in an Excel document and I would find it a lot smoother and less of a mental load if I could just focus on the contents of one cell at a time, rather than having my attention flitting back and forth between many cells on screen.

Apart from just zooming in, is there a way, within Excel or with an external tool, to display one cell at a time, and navigate to adjacent cells with the keyboard's arrow keys, or something to similar effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to make all rows the same height, and all columns the same width, you could resize your Excel window to be show only one cell at a time.

If you find the resulting size of the display too small, you could then increase the sizes of rows and columns until the single cell in the window, and the window itself, were a size you liked. However, as `Viki Ji` says, there is a maximum for both.

My guess is that, if you don't wish to so a fairly simple amplification of the Excel display, you don't want to be resizing rows and columns, then presumably back again when done with the task.

In that case, creating a User Form with only a single cell's content displayed in it would be the way to go, most likely. Add buttons to move all four directions so you can move from cell to cell as desired, and make sure the address of the cell is displayed adequately for your need.

You could even use a VBA macro to begin by hiding all cell contents except the current cell. It's operating functionality would be to, upon entering a different cell, hide the last cell's material and unhide the new cell's material. It might do this by "hiding" all rows except the current row and "hiding" all columns except the current column. You would use your arrow keys to move from cell to cell.

Literally "hiding" rows and columns isn't, of course, a working idea... impossible to navigate to an actually hidden one of either whether via arrow keys or mouse. Any other way to navigate would be much harder (harder than changing the magnification...). So you'd instead change heights and widths to "0.1" which is pretty much just a thick black like made up of two side-by-side row or column borders, but it WOULD allow you to use arrow keys for moving from one to another. Clicking might take supreme skill, but arrowing would be simple. "0.1" is pretty much Excel's lower limit for row or column size if using normal size fonts so it's the value to use.

My guess is creating a user form is the way you'd most prefer. You could even size it so that it covers the whole Excel cell region and so completely minimize Excel distractions and make focusing on ONLY the one cell's contents radically easier. It's not overly hard to learn to do either, with tutorials all over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to increase the row height and column width of the cell.
Besides, please note that the [maximum limit for Column width and Row height are 255 characters and 409 points](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:%7E:text=Worksheet%20and%20workbook%20specifications%20and%20limits), respectively.